# USER_PRESENT intent reason

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I'm building a Camera app and I want to make use of the hardware shutter found on some devices too. When the app is already launched, pressing the hardware button captures a photo properly (using android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON). When Im looking at the home screen, pressing the button launches the app properly too. My question is about the Lock screen. Is there any way I can launch the app if the button is pressed with the lock screen active? I have no password set so pressing the button with the lock screen active just unlocks the device. My feeling is that it should be solved by android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT , but it triggers everytime the device is unlocked in any way. Can I somehow detect if it was the camera button that triggered the USER_PRESENT broadcast? Or any other way how it could be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let’s explore the variety of ways the screen becomes unblanked.

1. the user pushed the power button, either intentionally or not (think
   butt dialing)
2. an application decided to unblank the screen, such as:
   the phone app, which unblanks the screen for an incoming call
   messaging apps, such as GoSMS, wh ich unblank the screen when a
   message arrives any other app may do this

All this will trigger the USER_PRESENT Intent. So, the answer is no - you can not rely on this intent.

Comment: ye I know that, I was hoping for some hidden flag or something extra in the intent that would display what caused the USER_PRESENT broadcast, but havent found anything. Not sure how to do it for now.